# Create draft emails and save in folder other than the default Drafts folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I have written code that pulls information from an Excel table to an Outlook template.

I would like two more things.

1. Instead of saving the emails in "Draft" I would like to make a new folder called "Reclass" and save the unsent emails there.
2. Using a If statement (I think) so only the users (this is a section in my Excel table that I am pulling from for the MailTo part of my email) that have Y in their row (Reclass column in the table has either Y or N in it) will get a email drafted to be sent on a later date.

   ```
   Public Enum EmailColumns
       ecEmailAdresses = 44
       ecSubject = 43
   End Enum
   Public Sub SaveEmails()
       Dim r As Long
       'The With Statement allows the user to "Perform a series of statements on a specified object without specifying the name of the object multiple times"
       '.Cells(.Row.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row actually refers to ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Data insert").Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row
       With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Report")
           '.Cells(): references a cell or range of cells on Worksheets("Data insert")
           '.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses): References the last cell in column 43 of the worsheet
           '.End(xlUp): Changes the reference from the last cell to the first used cell above the last cell in column 44
           '.Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdressess).End(xlUp).Row: returns the Row number of the last cell column 44
           For r = 2 To .Cells(.Rows.Count, ecEmailAdresses).End(xlUp).Row
               getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo:=.Cells(r, ecEmailAdresses), Subject:=.Cells(r, ecSubject)).Save
           Next
       End With

   End Sub
   Public Function getPOAccrualTemplate(MailTo As String, Optional CC As String, Optional BC As String, Optional Subject As String) As Object
       Const TEMPLATE_PATH As String = "C:\Users\JoeDoe\Documents\Project\Email Template.oft"
       Dim OutApp As Object, OutMail As Object
       'CreateObject("Outlook.Application"): Creates an instance of an Outlook Application.
       'Outlook.Application.CreatItemFromTemplate returns a new MailItem Based on a saved email Template
       Set OutMail = CreateObject("Outlook.Application").CreateItemFromTemplate(TEMPLATE_PATH)

       With OutMail
           .To = MailTo
           .CC = CC
           .BCC = BC
           .Subject = Subject
       End With
       'Returns the new MailItem to the caller of the function
       Set getTemplate = OutMail

   End Function
   ```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using `Application.CreateItemFromTemplate`, use `MAPIFolder.Items.Add`, where `MAPIFolder` is a folder retrieved from OOM. Assuming that folder is on the same level as the Drafts folder, try something like the following:

```
set app = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
set ns = app.GetNamespace("MAPI")
ns.Logon
set drafts = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderDrafts)
on error resume next 'the line below can raise an exception if the folder is not found
set myFolder = drafts.Parent.Folders("Reclass")
if myFolder Is Nothing Then
  set myFolder = drafts.Parent.Folders.Add("Reclass")
end If
set OutMail = myFolder.Items.Add
```

Comment: Also, what is 'ns.Logon' doing?